# Making of a customer report based on sales

Tags: python, django, report, django-annotate

I am trying to make a customer wise sales report, in it there will customers listed with their total number of sales, total amount, total paid and balance of sales occurred in the selected time period.

models:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...


class Sale(models.Model):
    auto_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sale_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField()

    customer = models.ForeignKey('customers.Customer', limit_choices_to={'is_deleted': False}, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sale_category = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=SALE_CATEGORY, default="intra_state")

    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    round_off = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, default=0.00, max_digits=30)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    paid = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0.00, max_digits=15)

    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

What I tried is passing customers with sales occurred in the time period and using a template tag getting the sale values of each customer in template

views:

```py
def customer_sales_report(request):
    from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
    to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')

    filter_form = {
        'from_date': from_date,
        'to_date': to_date,
    }

    from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
    to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%d/%m/%Y')

    sales = Sale.objects.filter(sale_date__date__range=[from_date, to_date], is_deleted=False)
    customer_pks = list(sales.values_list('customer_id', flat=True))
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(pk__in=customer_pks, is_deleted=False)

    filter_string = f"{filter_form['from_date']},{filter_form['to_date']}"

    context = {
        'customers': customers,
        'filter_form': filter_form,
        'filter_string': filter_string,
        "title": 'Customer sales report',
    }

    return render(request, 'customers/customer_sales_report.html', context)
```

template:

```html
...
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 30px;">ID</th>
            <th>Name </th>
            <th>Phone </th>
            <td>Sales</td>
            <td>Total Amount</td>
            <td>Paid Amount</td>
            <td>Balance Amount</td>
            <td>Customer Balance</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% load el_pagination_tags %}
        {% paginate 20 customers %}
        {% for instance in customers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="" href="{% url 'customers:customer' pk=instance.pk %}" >{{ instance }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ instance.phone }}</td>

            {% with instance.pk|get_customer_sales:filter_string as sales %}
            <td>{{ sales.total_count }}</td>
            <td>{{ sales.subtotal }}</td>
            <td>{{ sales.paid }}</td>
            <td>{{ sales.balance }}</td>
            <td>{{ sales.current_balance }} ({{ sales.current_balance_type }})</td>
            {% endwith %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

</table>
...
```

template tag:

```py
@register.filter
def get_customer_sales(pk, data):
    list_data = data.split(',')

    from_date = list_data[0]
    to_date = list_data[1]
    from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

    sales = Sale.objects.filter(customer_id=pk, sale_date__date__range=[from_date, to_date], is_deleted=False)
    subtotal_amount = sales.aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum']
    sale_payment = sales.aggregate(Sum('paid'))['paid__sum']
    sale_balance = sales.aggregate(Sum('balance'))['balance__sum']
    ...

    sale_data = {
        'total_count': sales.count(),
        'paid': sale_payment,
        'balance': sale_balance,
        'subtotal': subtotal_amount,
        "current_balance" : current_balance,
        "current_balance_type" : current_balance_type,
    }

    return sale_data
```

What I need now is to order by their total amount which as of now I am unable to do. is there a way I can annotate the total amount, paid, balance of sales in to customers queryset which will make it easier or any other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible to do via annotation and will even be more efficient since all calculations are made in a single query instead of a `3 * NRows`.

We can achieve that with the [Filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

BTW, you don't need the `list()` for customer_pks, it should be more efficient to allow DB to work directly on a query.

```
sales = Sale.objects.filter(sale_date__date__range=[from_date, to_date], is_deleted=False)
customers = Customer.objects.filter(pk__in=sales.values('customer_id'), is_deleted=False)

sales_q = Q(sales__sale_date__date__range=[from_date, to_date], sales__is_deleted=False)
customers = customers.annotate(
    subtotal_amount=Sum('sales__total', filter=sales_q),
    sale_payment=Sum('sales__paid', filter=sales_q),
    sale_balance=Sum('sales__balance', filter=sales_q),
)
```

I don't know what is `current_balance` and `current_balance_type`, so you'll need to figure it out by yourself or amend the question.

P.S. you don't have to covert dates to the `filter_string` - you can pass any type of objects to the template and then to the filter.

Comment: `current_balance` is alright i have a function for it. I had other variables to be passed to the template tag, just showed wanted things, can only pass 2 at a time so I combined them to form a string and passed only 2.

Comment: So does the above solve your task? If yes, please accept/upvote

Comment: Oh, I didn't know filters are limited to 2 arguments only...Well, you can always pass a dict/tuple as an argument (i.e. `filter_form`) to avoid parse-format-parse cycle and copy-pasting the parsing code

Comment: I have another doubt, since I don't have a field discount_amount i need to calculate it from `subtotal - total`, can I add filter inside F() also?

Comment: No, you cannot, however, you can subtract sums after the aggregation, like this `F('subtotal_amount') - F('sale_payment')`. This should probably also work: `Sum(F('sales__total') - F('sales__paid'), filter=sales_q)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

order_by()
order_by(*fields)

By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the order_by method.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: Actually yes but no, i have a query-set of customers i need it to be ordered by their corresponding aggregated sales total or balance total which are not fields in Customer model.